# I would like to add y-axis labels to my tikz drawing at the given values (0, 0.05, 0.1, ..., 0.5)

Tags: tikz-styles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \begin{document}
    %me learning how to draw stuff in tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (17,0) node[right]  {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,10) node[above] {$f(x)$};
\draw (1,-1) rectangle (3,0);
\draw (3,-1) rectangle (5,0);
\draw (5,-1) rectangle (7,0);
\draw (7,-1) rectangle (9,0);
\draw (9,-1) rectangle (11,0);
\draw (11,-1) rectangle (13,0);
\draw (13,-1) rectangle (15,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\foreach \y in {0,0.05,...,0.5}{\node at (-.8,\y) {\y};}` will not be very pleasing. Please try to get your code right so that it fits on one page. Then you might explain (in text, not in the title) what you need. As it stands now, your question is not very clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, using a loop. It uses the `\foreach` command, which has syntax:

```
\foreach <control sequence> in {<first number>,<second number>,...,<last number>}{%
<do this>
}%
```

The trick here is that the first and second number have a specific delta, which the parser will remember for the interdistance between loops. The last number is the last element to be evaluated, obviously.

I've also used `\pgfmathprintnumber` to pretty print the numbers. The syntax is kind of obvious, but the optional argument (between the `[` and `]`) can hold a rather long list of possible options, reiterating here would hold little value. You may want to use your own format, to do so, please consult the documentation which came with your distribution. The documentation can be prompted using `texdoc pgfmanual` or `texdoc tikz`. My version of the `tikz` manual has number printing on page 950.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (17,0) node[right]  {$x$}; 
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,10.5) node[above] {$f(x)$};% increased y height by .5
\draw (1,-1) rectangle (3,0);
\draw (3,-1) rectangle (5,0);
\draw (5,-1) rectangle (7,0);
\draw (7,-1) rectangle (9,0);
\draw (9,-1) rectangle (11,0);
\draw (11,-1) rectangle (13,0);
\draw (13,-1) rectangle (15,0);
\foreach\i in {0,1,...,10}{%
\pgfmathparse{\i/20}%
\edef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}
\draw (-.2,\i) -- (0,\i);
\node at (-.75,\i){$\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2,fixed,fixed zerofill]{\tmp}$};%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You may also want to look at the `pgfplots` package if the graph you intend to draw is relatively more complex.

Comment: I realize you added the first % sign for the comment "increased y by .5", but why did you add the other % signs in the code you added?

Comment: Another question I have is what is edef tmp, and pgfmathresult used for. I searched the documentation and did not find definition.

Comment: @user3784943 In LaTeX, starting a new line in the editor has a semantic meaning (the same meaning as using a space character. A % is intended to be a comment, but it can also gobble the space that starting a new line creates.

Comment: @user3784943 The second question is about \pgfmathparse. When using the command \pgfmathparse, you can do basic arithmetic with the standard mathematical operators, like division (`/`), multiplication, addition, etc. (here I divided \i by 20). The result of that calculation is stored in \pgfmathresult. To pretty print the numbers, I want to separate the evaluation and the printing part of the calculation. The evaluation part is done by \pgfmathparse, so I want to have some temporary macro which holds \pgfmathresult. \edef makes sure that the result is fully expanded

Comment: (the expanded form of \pgfmathresult is the actual number that follows from the arithmetic we fed to \pgfmathparse.) Anyway, we pass on the macro that holds the completely expanded value (these are the values you see as the y-tick values), and then print them, together with some formatting (2 digits after the period, use a fixed format and the amount of zeroes after the period).

Answer (score 1):

`TikZ` and `pgfplots` are not the same programs. Actually, `pgfplots` is based on TikZ and is dedicated for drawing diagrams. For learning them, you need to read their manuals (for TikZ at least chapter 3: TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm). There is a lot examples which you lead to desired knowledge :-)

For your MWE in TikZ try:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm] {standalone}%{article} 

    \begin{document}
%me learning how to draw stuff in tikz 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (14,0) node[right] {$x$}; 
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,8) node[above] {$f(x)$}; 
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,13}% for x ticks and labels
    \draw (\i,0.1) --  (\i,-0.1) node[below] {\i}; 
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,7}% for y ticks and labels
    \draw (0.1,\i) --  (-0.1,\i) node[left] {\i};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:** Some explanation: 
`\foreach` loops I used in calculation of axis tick and label positions. Shoved is simple case, when tick labels are integer. As you mentioned in your question title, you like to have `y` range between 0 and 0.5 in steps 0.05. For this labels you need to change `y \foreach` loop to

```
\foreach \i in {0,0.05,...,0.51}
    \draw (0.1,15*\i) --  (-0.1,15*\i) node[left] {\pgfmathprintnumber{\i}};
```

where I use mathematical engine (part of TikZ) for cutting label numbers to two decimals.